# How do you add external codebase to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

OK I give up. I've been trying to do this for the past two hours I googled how to add external source to eclipse, how to import, how to add to build path etc. and I must say there is absolutely nothing that clearly states how do you do this.

I want to add a directory with some Java classes. I downloaded it from github. It has a package some.package.name in its header.

I tried drag and dropping it to my project, adding it via build paths, using the import button. I tried changing the package names.

I always get this "RED X" icon next to the folder names ( these folder names are called like the package string in the headers ). This isn't even annotated so I do not know what am I even doing wrong. Why doesn't eclipse accept these sources? They are already in the project tree I do not understand this.

Can somebody actually tell me how you are supposed to do this? And why is this so complicated? Why would people create a IDE with I suppose a million lines of code and then make it be so hard to do the simplest thing?

Sorry for the rant but I am seriously starting to hate Java.

Comment: 'I want to add a directory with some Java classes' - `.class` or `.java` files?

Comment: These are .java files